# Proper way to seed routes for view spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

I am testing my views with RSpec. Due to some changes, there is now a call to `url_for` in the view and all the spec that I wrote for `show` actions are failing:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"events", :action=>"show"}
```

The `:id` part is missing and because of that the call fails.

(I know that I can just stub that failing method call)

The [only thing I found](http://shannonwells.livejournal.com/10078.html) is pretty old and looks like a bad workaround. Also the [RSpec documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-0/docs/view-specs/view-spec#passing-spec-with-before-and-nesting) does not show something helpful.

Is there a proper way to tell RSpec that it should be on something like `events/123`?

**Some more context:**

In the view 
I call a helper, something like this:

```
def some_helper_method
  url_for(only_path: false)} + "something_else"
end
```

The call to that method fails with

```
 Failure/Error: render
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   No route matches {:controller=>"events", :action=>"show"}
```

I'm currently fixing it by stubbing the call to that method `view.stub(some_helper_method: 'SOME_URL')`

Comment: Are you using stub_model ? If so, I think can provide you the proper answer. I know that the best practice on creating view specs is stubbing models (including the id part of it), otherwise you run into very slow view specs, and that will be a really drawback to your test suite.

Comment: no, i'm using factory girl, but how would `stub_model` help with that

Comment: If you were using stub_model I would say that when assigning the stubbed model to the view in the view spec, the missing `:id` would be the cause of the problem. With `FactoryGirl.create` this shouldn't be an issue, because an `id` is provided after the creation. Could you paste the spec and the url_for declaration of the view ? I don't think this is a hard thing to track down and I would be glad to help ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeFranco I added some more context. you can actually reproduce it by removing the call to stub `likes` here https://github.com/phoet/on_ruby/blob/master/spec/views/events/show.html_spec.rb

Comment: Please, try the following solution: `assign(:event, event)` before rendering. I think that it might work. If so, I'll transform it into an answer, since it is the most plausible solution.

Comment: nope, does not help. i event tried it in a `before` block.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, I think I found your answer. I cloned your repo and debug **a lot =P** until I found that you **need to infer the desired parameters** in your view spec, since rspec-rails only provides the `:controller` parameter for the view being rendered. Well, in an attempt to understand better what the issue is, I found this explanation in the rspec-rails documentation:

> > View specs infer the controller name and path from the path to the view template. e.g. if the template is "events/index.html.erb" then:
> >
> > `controller.controller_path == "events"`
> >     `controller.request.path_parameters[:controller] == "events"`
> >
> > This means that most of the time you don't need to set these values. When spec'ing a partial that is included across different controllers, you may need to override these values before rendering the view

In other words, the previous [link](http://shannonwells.livejournal.com/10078.html) that you posted still works and is still the solution for the parameters "issue" in your view spec. You can follow the discussion about the topic in this [PullRequest](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/172) thread.

So, the conclusion is that if you really don't want to stub out your call to `url_for` helper (or the helper that is calling it), you need to supply the desired `:id` parameter since there's no route for any show action without an `:id` param (as pointed out by you). Our final result (tested) is indeed:

`controller.request.path_parameters[:id] = event.id`

If this a workaround ? I really don't think so, since **rspec-rails itself is internally using this feature to provide the `:controller` param.**

I'm sorry I couldn't be more helpful before, but I think that this closes all of our main doubts.

My opinion ? If you really don't need to make any assertions based on the `url_for` behavior (or any helper behavior for that matter), just stub it, since it is expected to already have been tested in isolation. Otherwise, use the `:id` param, and don't worry about it. It is **not** a workaround.

Cheers friend !

Comment: it would be awesome to have something like `describe "events/show/123"` do the whole job!

Comment: We agree on that ! @phoet

Comment: I really wish I found this before debugging my tests for 3 hours and nearly figuring out the solution myself.

Answer (score -2):

If you will face the id problem the try this in your route.rb

```
get "events/show/:id", :to=> "events#show"
```

Comment: As said in the question, the problem is because url_for is building an url for a model without an id. It's not a Route issue.